# How to return all matched embedded array documents excluding all other field in array meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have following collection. "addedDetails" is a embedded array document. i want to match HM project and retrieve corresponding value in kk dash board

```
{
        "_id" : "eJHHpB4DkBfLh9kQH",
        "dashBoardName" : "kk",
        "addedDetails" : [
                {
                        "jid" : "reZYYfWxP9Da9FdZP",
                        "job" : "job1",
                        "project" : "HM",
                        "buildStatus" : "FAILURE"
                },
                {
                        "jid" : "KvBcagCuB9DtZa9Wm",
                        "job" : "job 2",
                        "project" : "HM",
                        "buildStatus" : "SUCCESS"
                },
                {
                        "jid" : "raiTB4mQ5TmE2d2Jn",
                        "job" : "job3",
                        "project" : "CEI",
                        "buildStatus" : "FAILURE"
                },
                {
                        "jid" : "rEmuq6Shtz2vW6Pf3",
                        "job" : "job4",
                        "project" : "RI",
                        "buildStatus" : "FAILURE"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "muzA3wjGYfk9Ye5pE",
        "dashBoardName" : "ss",
        "addedDetails" : [
                {
                        "jid" : "MkTsPB5xgkZKGShSq",
                        "job" : "job1",
                        "project" : "HM",
                        "buildStatus" : "SUCCESS"
                }
        ]
}
```

Expected retun value:

```
 {
        "_id" : "eJHHpB4DkBfLh9kQH",
                    "dashBoardName" : "kk",
                    "addedDetails" : [
                            {
                                    "jid" : "reZYYfWxP9Da9FdZP",
                                    "job" : "job1",
                                    "project" : "HM",
                                    "buildStatus" : "FAILURE"
                            },
                            {
                                    "jid" : "KvBcagCuB9DtZa9Wm",
                                    "job" : "job2",
                                    "project" : "HM",
                                    "buildStatus" : "SUCCESS"
                            }
        ]}
    }
```

my query:

```
'listjobName': function(){
return     dashBoard.find({"dashBoardName":"kk","addedDetails.project":"HM"},{addedDetails: { $all: [{ "$elemMatch" : { project: "HM" }}]}} );
}
```

Please some one help me to correct the query. here all the value in dash board kk is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "dashBoardName": "kk"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$addedDetails'
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $match: {
                'addedDetails.project': 'HM'
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    _id: '$_id',
                    dashboardName: '$dashBoardName'
                },
                addedDetails: {
                    $addToSet: '$addedDetails'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $project: {
                dashBoardName: '$_id.dashboardName',
                _id: '$_id._id',
                addedDetails: 1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Thnk you so much for your quick replay. can this be done without using aggregate function?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection_name.aggregate( [ 
{ $unwind : "$addedDetails" },  
{ $match : 
  { 
    $and: [ { "dashBoardName" : "kk" }, { "addedDetails.project" : "HM" } ] 
  } 
},
{ $group : 
  { _id : " $_id", 
   dashBoardName : { $first : "$dashBoardName"}, 
   addedDetails : { $push : "$addedDetails" } 
  } 
}
])
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "eJHHpB4DkBfLh9kQH",
    "dashBoardName" : "kk",
    "addedDetails" : [ 
        {
            "jid" : "reZYYfWxP9Da9FdZP",
            "job" : "job1",
            "project" : "HM",
            "buildStatus" : "FAILURE"
        }, 
        {
            "jid" : "KvBcagCuB9DtZa9Wm",
            "job" : "job 2",
            "project" : "HM",
            "buildStatus" : "SUCCESS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is returning nothing

Comment: Have you replaced collection_name with the collection name you wish to search!?